# How to post data to server from client( using post method in recyclerview custom adapter) using retrofit library

Tags: android, retrofit2

When I put it at Activity. It's still normal active. But put it in  item click event of recyclerview .then it not active. Can anyone put post method in item click?.
And my code:

```
  public MyViewHolder(View view){
        super(view);
        txt=view.findViewById(R.id.txt_item_rec);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int pos=getAdapterPosition();
                if(pos!=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),strings.get(pos),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    APIService mapi= ApiUtils.getAPIService();
                    mapi.importFileExcel(strings.get(pos)).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                                try {
                                    Toast.makeText(context,response.body().string(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What difference does it make in Adapter . just create a Utility network class and use it throughout the application .

Comment: not active? are you getting any error ?

Comment: it's still get data of this item but couldn't post to server (using retrofit library)

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
   public MyViewHolder(View view){
             super(view);
             txt=view.findViewById(R.id.txt_item_rec);
             itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

First of all, you're using `itemView` but you're passing `view` to your `MyViewHolder` and then to `super`. You should replace it with `view`

The second issue may be that you can't get position in ViewHolder you get it in `onBindViewHolder` as a viewholder is just a model for your row.

An example how to do it in `onBindViewHolder` method

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               //move your code here;
            }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

onBindViewHolder is a totally wrong place for any listeners, you can get position easily on Custom view holder using getLayoutPosition() and getAdapterPosition().

```
public MyViewHolder(View view){
    super(view);
    txt=view.findViewById(R.id.txt_item_rec);
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int pos=getAdapterPosition();
            if(pos!=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),strings.get(pos),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                APIService mapi= ApiUtils.getAPIService();
                mapi.importFileExcel(strings.get(pos)).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                        if(response.isSuccessful()){
                            try {
                                Toast.makeText(context,response.body().string(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```